# Running sql script in Jenkins using SQLcl

Tags: jenkins, sqlcl

I am newbie in Jenkins and I would like to use Oracle SQLcl to run sql query before starting the job.

Earlier I planned to use SQLPlus Script Runner but it requires additional software(Oracle SQL*Plus) and I cannot install it on the machine.

Oracle SQLcl doesn't need anything more so I think it can be solution.

Is it possible to run sql query using SQLcl in "Execute Windows batch command" textbox ? (or execute command to run sql script from the file)

Or maybe I can do this by using "Execute shell" ?

So far I did:

In the "Execute Windows batch" textbox I typed:

```
cd .\sqlcl\bin
sql userName/passw@//test_database_address:port
@test.sql
```

test.sql contains simple simple sql query.

After running my Jenkins job I see:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database ...
Disconnected from Oracle Database ...
\sqlcl\bin> exit 0
```

Comment: Your connection is working...what's in your sql script?

Comment: sorry for the late answer, to be sure that my script is ok I used only simple query: 
select 1 from dual;
but result is the same - exit 0

Comment: I found out that exit 0 is correct return code when script ended properly